# How to use dojo/behavior on dojo widget?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dojo, behavior

I read this article ([Using dojo.behavior](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/using_behavior/)), and want to use the [behavior](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/behavior.html) module in my project as event handling module.

But I have a problem that, for DOM nodes, it works wonderful, but how can I use it on the Dojo widgets?

If I use dojo/on module, I can do it like this:

```
var buttonNode = dijit.byId("myButton");
on(buttonNode, "onClick", buttonHandler);
```

or

```
dijit.byId("myButton").onClick = buttonHandler;
```

But, if I use behavior module,

```
behavior.add({
    "#myButton": {
        onClick: buttonHandler
    }
});
```

it doesn't work. (Of course I called behavior.apply() after I finished page render.)
The code below doesn't work either.

```
behavior.add({
    "[widgetid='myButton']": {
        onClick: buttonHandler
    }
});
```

After some investigation, I found the reason the code above not work is because a button widget is composed by many s and an inner . And if I use the id specified by data-dojo-id, it will point to a  instead of the  that I hope the event bind with.

I found a solution which can walk out this situation,

```
behavior.add({
  "[widgetid='myButton'] input": {
    onclick: buttonHandler
  }
}
```

but the css selector is too complex and it depends on what type the widget is.

Is there a good solution to apply dojo/behavior on widgets just like on dom nodes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you really what is to hook up an event on the widget object, but `behavior` is designed to access the DOM instead. So, I think you're stuck with your workaround.

Comment: Yes. What you said is exactly the problem I am facing. Do you have any good solution?